# Not getting PushKit notifications on application downloaded from AppStore

Tags: ios, callkit, pushkit

I am not getting PushKit notification on application downloaded from AppStore. Though it works fine if I install it directly from XCode.

I am using PushKit along with CallKit for VoIP calls.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple server used for Production mode is api.push.apple.com:443, whereas the server used for Development mode is api.sandbox.push.apple.com:443

Read here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns

Make sure the backend mechanism addresses the correct server for each mode.

Comment: Thank you so much mate, I was stuck on this issue for the past 2 days. God bless you.